# Excel 2010 conditional formatting dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I want to have a conditional formatting set up so that when there is a date in row B, the date in row A is turned to strikethrough and is highlighted; If no date in row B, row A stays the same.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible though I did struggle with getting it to undo if the date is removed from column B.  Hopefully, you won't have to do this.

It's all down to Excel being able to recognise a date and change the format automatically.

Go to Conditional Format => New Rule and select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format"

In the box, type =CELL("format",$B1)="D1" where B1 is the cell you're entering dates into.

Choose your formatting type then click Okay (or apply).  Copy and paste as necessary.

The date must then be entered in the format dd/mm/yy or dd/mm/yyyy.  When you do this, column A will change as per your formatting requirements.

Source: https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2014/06/17/excel-conditional-formatting-dates/#value-changed-to-date

Comment: You can create another Rule in A for =B1="" without format then in Manage Rule on this new rule click `Stop if True`

Comment: @yass You are correct but OP asked for conditional formatting when a date is entered into column B.  If column B is also used for notes (shouldn't be, but you never know) then this would also trigger the conditional formatting in your example.

Comment: Let OP create a convenient  second rule in order to use it to stop the first when True (I meant that in my first comment)